# Editing and Deleting Query Tables in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, sql, query

How do I edit the query for a Query Table after it has been created?

How do I permanently delete a Query Table? Even after I do right-click -> remove, it still appears in dropdown lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to edit the query table after it was created in ArcMap. You might like using [Query Layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000027000000) available since ArcGIS 10.0 - there you can edit the SQL expression used by going to the Layer Properties window > Source tab > Change query.

Not exactly sure what drop-down list you refer to.

Comment: was referring to the lists of feature classes for selecting inputs for the various tools.